# How to determine the sequence using inequality?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In this question, we consider sequences consisting of five digits.

Determine the number of 5-digit sequences $d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5$, whose digits are decreasing,i.e., $d_1> d_2 > d_3 > d_4 > d_5.$

Determine the number of 5-digit sequences $d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5$, whose digits are non-increasing,i.e., $d_1\ge d_2\ge d_3\ge d_4\ge d_5$.

Hint: Consider the numbers $x_1=d_1-d_2, x_2=d_2-d_3, x_3=d_3-d_4, x_4=d_4-d_5, x_5=d_5$
What do you know about $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5?$

I think it is asking for an inequality but I am not sure how to use concepts of combinatorics for this question.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for typing your remarks

Comment: For the first case - what are the restrictions on each $x_i$?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the set of digits is the set of decimal digits $D = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$.

> Determine the number of $5$-digit sequences $d_1d_2d_3d_4d_5$ whose digits are strictly decreasing.

Observe that if we choose a subset of five digits from set $D$, there is only one way to arrange them so that $d_1 < d_2 < d_3 < d_4 < d_5$.

> Determine the number of $5$-digit sequences $d_1d_2d_3d_4d_5$ whose digits are non-increasing.

Observe that since $x_1 = d_1 - d_2$, $x_2 = d_2 - d_1$, $x_3 = d_3 - d_2$, $x_4 = d_4 - d_5$, $x_5 = d_5$, $d_1 \leq 9$, and $d_5 \geq 0$, 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = d_5 - d_1 \leq 9 - 0 = 9$$
where the inequality 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \leq 9 \tag{1}$$
is an inequality in the nonnegative integers.  If we set $$s = 9 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)$$ then $s$ is a nonnegative integer satisfying
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + s = 9 \tag{2}$$
The number of non-increasing sequences of length $5$ is the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers.

Alternatively, let $y_k$ be the number of occurrences of the digit $k$ in the sequence $d_1d_2d_3d_4d_5$.  Then 
$$y_0 + y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 + y_7 + y_8 + y_9 = 5 \tag{3}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  The number of non-increasing sequences of length $5$ is the number of solutions of equation 3 in the nonnegative integers.